# What is recursion and how does it work?

Tags: ruby, recursion

Could someone please explain what exactly recursion is (and how it works in Ruby, if that's not too much to ask for). I came across a lengthy code snippet relying on recursion and it confused me (I lost it now, and it's not entirely relevant).

Comment: how is the code not relevant if that's what had you confused? And recursion is a general principal in computing that can be performed in most languages, it is not a concept specific to Ruby

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A recursive function/method calls itself. For a recursive algorithm to terminate you need a base case (e.g. a condition where the function does **not** call itself recursively) and you also need to make sure that you get closer to that base case in each recursive call. Let's look at a very simple example:

```
def countdown(n)
  return if n.zero? # base case
  puts n
  countdown(n-1)    # getting closer to base case 
end               

countdown(5)
5
4
3
2
1
```

Some problems can be very elegantly expressed with recursion, e.g a lot of mathematical functions are described in a recursive way.

Answer (score 36):

To understand recursion, you first need to understand recursion.

Now, on a serious note, a recursive function is one that calls itself. One classic example of this construct is the fibonacci sequence:

```
def fib(n)
  return n if (0..1).include? n
  fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) if n > 1
end
```

Using recursive functions gives you great power, but also comes with a lot of responsability (pun intended) and it presents some risk. For instance, you could end up with stack overflows (I'm on a roll) if your recursiveness is too big :-)

Comment: You are right @changeloge. Long time ago, while playing with irb I didn't get result for more than 5 minutes while using the above code with big Fibonacci sequence "55". I found Hash is more faster like so:
fibonacci = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = k < 2 ? k : h[k-1] + h[k-2] }

Answer (score 5):

**Ruby on Rails** example:

Recursion will generate array of parents parents

**a/m/document.rb**

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Document'

  def self.get_ancestors(who)
    @tree ||= []
    # @tree is instance variable of Document class object not document instance object
    # so: Document.get_instance_variable('@tree')

    if who.parent.nil?
      return @tree
    else
      @tree << who.parent
      get_ancestors(who.parent)
    end
  end

  def ancestors
    @ancestors ||= Document.get_ancestors(self)
  end

end
```

**console**:

```
d = Document.last
d.ancestors.collect(&:id)
# => [570, 569, 568]
```

https://gist.github.com/equivalent/5063770

Answer (score 2):

Typically recursion is about method calling themselves, but maybe what you encountered were recursive structures, i.e. objects referring to themselves. Ruby 1.9 handles these really well:

```
h = {foo: 42, bar: 666}
parent = {child: {foo: 42, bar: 666}}
h[:parent] = parent
h.inspect # => {:foo=>42, :bar=>666, :parent=>{:child=>{...}}}

x = []
y = [x]
x << y
x.inspect # => [[[...]]]
x == [x]  # => true
```

I find that last line is quite wicked; I [blogged](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2009/05/lost-in-recursion.html) about this kind of issues with comparison of recursive structures a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add to the answers in here that every recursion algorithm is composed of two things:

1. base case
2. recursive case

Base case is what tells your algorithm to break out so it does not continue to infinity or your memory runs out.

Recursive case is the part that ensures to call itself but shaving or shrinking the arguments you are calling it with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it is the other way to write iterative code but keep in mind it is memory expensive also only recommended for those kind of problems which remains same in nature even after reducing problem size.
for example:
if you are trying to solve tower of hanoi problem or finding factorial then recursion is recommended iterative approach will be more LOC and hard to understand
but if you are just finding simple palindrome then use iterative.