# What constitutes a stack level too deep error? Code Kata

Tags: ruby

I have this code which I am trying to combine but I keep getting a stack level too deep error:

```
def zeros(n)
  trailing_zeros(n) if n == 1
  zeros(n-1) * n
end

def trailing_zeros(number)
 sort_sum = number.to_s.split(//).reverse
 counter = 0
 until sort_sum[counter] != "0"
  counter += 1
 end
 counter
end

puts zeros(5)
```

Individually, they work fine, but when I try to combine them, I run into problems and I don't understand why. Why does this constitute as a stack level too deep. From an experienced developer. What would cue you off that this would be an error of that type?
I understand that infinite recursions or something with a really big number could cause it but what's the limit? Also, I read from wikipedia, that these type of errors also have something to do with the system that your running and the amount of memory it can use or allocate to the methods. Is this true?

-------EDIT---------

Well, it doesn't matter if my question gets downvoted because I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I also wanted to mention that I did try to use return trailing_zeros(n) as you guys mentioned.

```
def zeros(n)
  return trailing_zeros(n) if n == 1
  zeros(n-1) * n
end
```

The only problem with this is that I get a value of 0. I've seen it by inserting a binding.pry. I know this is a noob question but I just don't see what is wrong here. Thanks guys for your patience.

-------EDIT------

To clarify, I'm trying to get the trailing zeros of a factorial. If I pass in 5, I will get 1 #120. If I pass a 12, I will get 2 #479001600

Comment: Your function zeros(n) is going into an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply manu29.d but could you please elaborate. Where exactly is this infinite loop taking place? Do you mean the trailing_zeros(n) part?

Comment: The fact is you are not terminating the execution of the function zeros(n) in any condition. There is no return statement. I think you should read more about [recursive functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418017/what-is-ruby-recursion-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: @DanRubio just to clarify: In ruby you can (and you are encouraged) to omit the `return` statement as any method returns the last expression evaluated. For example just `counter` instead of `return counter` is the way to go. In this example, however, you seem to want to break the flow in case of `n==1` so you must use the `return` statement, otherwise Ruby has no way of knowing your intention.

Comment: Hey @rkon thanks for your reply but if you guys could please bear with me here for a second. I've made an edit and I have tried to use the return function but if you guys could just illuminate to me what I'm doing, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey @manu29.d, thanks for your reply too but could u please also help me too with what is wrong with the return trailing_zero statement?

Comment: @DanRubio to be honest I can't get what you are trying to do :) Maybe you could quote the Kata you are coding for so we get the objective and understand what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: What do you expect to get from the combination of these functions?

Comment: sorry @rkon, what I wanted to do was to pass in a number such as 12 in the zeros function which would give me the factorial. Then I want to pass the factorial into the trailing_zero function to get the trailing zeros. If you have the time to help that'd be cool but if not that's cool too. I'll EVENTUALLY figure it out.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977727/the-number-of-trailing-zeros-in-a-factorial-of-a-given-number-ruby)@spundun shows how this calculation can be done without iterating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `zeros` function is trying to do too much. It can't calculate a factorial and at the same time count trailing zeroes in it.

If you think about it, while you are calculating the factorial, number of trailing zeroes may (and will) change. You're only interested in the final value. So first calculate that and only then count zeroes.

```
# inefficient(!) recursive calculation of factorial
# for more efficiency use loop
def factorial(n)
  raise "only positive values are allowed" if n < 0

  return 1 if n == 0
  n * factorial(n - 1)
end

def zeros(n)
  trailing_zeros(factorial(n))
end

def trailing_zeros(number)
 sort_sum = number.to_s.split(//).reverse
 counter = 0
 until sort_sum[counter] != "0"
  counter += 1
 end
 counter
end

zeros(5) # => 1
zeros(12) # => 2
```

Comment: Inside `factorial` you should check that `n >= 0`, otherwise for `n < 0` you will get a `SystemStackError`.

Comment: @toro2k: yeah-yeah. I was just thinking what to return for negative values. An error, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for this. @toro2k, what cued you off that there could be a potential systemsstackerror, is there a good resource you could refer to me that would show when a stacklevel error will or will not appear?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev An error is more than appropriate since the factorial operation is not defined for non-positive integers.

Comment: @DanRubio: if you pass negative n into current implementation of `factorial` it will never terminate and will recurse indefinitely until it runs out of stack space.

Comment: Got it. Thanks everyone for bearing with me on this one. I appreciate it.